# Java: How to fill out two arrays, alternating between the two

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that has two String arrays defined and initialized. I now want to accept inputs from the user to fill out the indexes of each array. I want the user to input index[i] for array 1 and then index[i] for array 2 and so on until both arrays are filled.

I attempted to use a nested loop to do this, but I was getting an out of bounds error.

Unfortunately, Google was not helpful as I kept finding the .fill() method, which I cannot currently use in my course.

The code below contains elements for the rest of the program which I haven't written. The below code is meant to complete the first part of the program and that is to get the list of words into the first two arrays and then output them to make sure they were filled correctly.

EDIT: Even though I got my answer, I tried updating the question for clarity. It looks like I was vastly overthinking the problem. It was my first time working with more than one array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

   public static int findWordInWordList(String[] wordList, String wordToFind, int numInList) {
      
      return -1; //Will replace words in a sentence, to be used coded and used later.
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] ogWords; //words to replace.
      String[] newWords; //words to replace with.
      String[] sentence; //the sentence that will be searched and have words replaced.
      int pairSize; //size of the first two arrays.
      
      pairSize = sc.nextInt();
      ogWords = new String[pairSize];
      newWords = new String[pairSize];
      
      for (int i = 0; i < ogWords.length; i++) {
         ogWords[i] = sc.next();
         
         for (int j = 0; j < newWords.length; j++) {
            newWords[j] = sc.next();
         }
      }
      
      for (int i = 0; i < pairSize - 1; i++) { //Testing arrays
      System.out.println(ogWords[i] + " " + newWords[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

The final for loop is just to test that the arrays were filled correctly, which isn't working right now :p.

Comment: please explain and comment out your code so it will give a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I've added comments to hopefully provide clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, I think you're after:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < pairSize; i++) {
     ogWords[i] = sc.next();
     newWords[i] = sc.next();
  }
```

Comment: No, you got it. I was vastly over-complicating it apparently. First time using multiple arrays and I don't know why I overthought the problem. Thank you so much!